# Two Careers Accounts

Tags: support, jobs, login, user-accounts, openid

I have a problem with Stack Overflow Careers. I somehow have two accounts created. Both are linked to my regular SO account via two different gmail email addresses (both emails are on my SO account, but each email has its own SOC profile). Can you please merge the two SOC profiles into one?